# Problem In Installing Visual Studio Any Version

Tags: visual-studio

I am having problem in installing visual studio "any version". First when i download the visual studio  community installer and then when i run the installer its downloading and installation completes then the installer window opens then at that time  it is showing me this error "it is not available in this version of windows. Try upgrading windows version." But i also upgraded it, but then it was showing the same error.   `<visual studio installing error>`

Comment: Can u give us your system version? and others usefull informations

Comment: Oh sorry Mr.Yannnicklngenierie,I am the first one to this system. The one update was not installed when I installed it then it worked.